# Getting to your seat on airplanes (or elsewhere)

Tags: questions, politeness

On airplanes, there are seats A(window)-B(middle)-C(isle) on one of the sides. Suppose someone is sitting on seat C and I need to get to seat B. What are the most natural ways to ask the person from seat C *give me the way* (is it the right way to put this?) to seat B?

What I can think of (not sure about correctness and the level of politeness):

> 1. Excuse me, can I seat there? [and point to seat B]
> 2. Excuse me, can I go past you?

Comment: I just stand there, smile, and look at the seat, raising my eyebrows expectantly, and only if they don't get the message, would I say "Excuse me, B23 is my seat". The situation (plane boarding, need to get everyone seated and belted), will mean that person sitting "outside" empty seats will be expecting someone to turn up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Excuse me..." would probably be sufficient, since it is pretty obvious what you would want to do. In fact smiling and looking hopeful is probably enough.  If you are sitting in the aisle seat and the window seat is empty you have to expect someone to turn up sooner or later.

"Excuse me, could I get past you" or "Can I get to seat B" would be completely clear and polite.